# MvcBuildViews and locating views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, msbuild

I have enabled MvcBuildViews task in my project file and I have found it finds and tries to build views that aren't in the project.

These views were totally out of date but not knowing whether to delete them or not from source I opted to relocate them (until I can find out) to a new folder called 'Obsolete'.

After relocating the view I try and build the project and it still somehow finds these views in the 'Obsolete' folder now.

How can I instruct the MvcBuildViews task to only compile views found in their usual search location and not everywhere in the project directory?

Answer (score 1):

So after doing some more hunting I find that the MvcBuildViews uses the aspnet_compiler.exe under the hood. It appears the only solution if I want to hand pick the locations is to point it at the specific folders themselves. My other option is to move the views outside of the project.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms229863(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms229863%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)